# vimscript : How do I apply a function on the current buffer?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I have written a function which capitalises the first letter of each word like this:

```
function! CamelCase() range
  let old = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
  for line in old
      let x = substitute(line,'\v<(.)(\w*)', '\u\1\L\2', 'g')
      echom x
  endfor
endfunction

command! -range=% CamelCase <line1>,<line2>call CamelCase()
```

Currently `:CamelCase()`displays the output in `:messsages` (because of `echom`)

How do i modify the function so it modifies the current buffer directly instead ? I have tried removing `echom x` and `let x=` but I get a large number of errors.

Comment: `setline(line, substitute(...))`, for one.

Comment: thank you, for some reason i had to use call : 
      call setline(line,substitute(line,'\v<(.)(\w*)', '\u\1\L\2', 'g')) . I don't understand when to use call and when not to quite yet.

Comment: Sorry, the `call` was implied in my comment but I should have been explicit. `function()` won't work without preceding it with `call` or something that consumes its output (e.g.`echo` or variable assignment). Commands are different...they can be called straight/unadorned.

Comment: A little more explicitly, if you are using the return value of `func()` (examples: `let foo = func()`, `echo func()`, `call otherfunc(func())`) then invocation of `func()` is implied. If you only care about the side-effects (i.e. you want to ignore/discard the returned value) then use `call` to invoke `func()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29) to set the contents of a line in the current buffer.

Which, in your case, should be enough, since you're changing line contents in place and not inserting or deleting lines. (There's [`appendbufline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#appendbufline%28%29) and [`deletebufline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#deletebufline%28%29) which can help with that.)

Note that in your case you don't need to have your function be a `range` function, since the behavior of `:call` of a non-range function with a range is to call it repeatedly for each line in the range. So that would implicitly loop over the lines for you.

This should be enough:

```
function! CamelCase()
    call setline('.',
       \ substitute(getline('.'),
       \ '\v<(.)(\w*)', '\u\1\L\2', 'g'))
endfunction
```

And you can keep the exact same command definition:

```
command! -range=% CamelCase <line1>,<line2>call CamelCase()
```